# Coalescing operator in linq query

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities, null-coalescing-operator

The use of the null-coalescing operator returns an error: `Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'int'`

When I hover over `days` it says `(range variable) int days`

```
var query = from date in dbdate.Dates
            join article in dbarticle.Articles on date.ArticleBarcode
                                               equals article.Barcode
            let days = article.Days
                    ?? dbgroup.Groups.Where(g => g.Number == article.GroupNumber)
                                .Select(g => g.Days).FirstOrDefault()

            where DbFunctions.AddDays(date.RunDate, days * -1) > DateTime.Now
            select article;
```

Comment: default int cannot be nullable. You have to use nullable int for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **cannot** store a *null* value into an int.

```
int a = null; // error !
```

What you want is a **nullable** int:

```
Nullable<int> a = null;
```

or

```
int? a = null;
```

Both are equivalent

In your example, `article.Days` must be *nullable*
You can configure it into your database and your entity will have nullable int for this property
Then, you will be able to use `??` on it in your linq query

Simple example:

```
int? a = null;
int b = a ?? 5; // if a is null then store 5, otherwise store value of a
```

Comment: @Justinlurman This does just creates another problem. The DbFunctions.AddDays won't work...

Comment: Well, you have no choice but implementing what i said if you're using `??`. Your problem with AddDays is another story. What about it ?

Comment: @Justinlurman It says: "The name 'DbFunctions' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: If found the problem. I was using EF5 so what I had to do instead was to use `date.RunDate.AddDays(days * -1)`